# Normalising issue for foreign key in template->instantiation model

Tags: database-design, foreign-keys

First of all, my platform is IBM i. That means I'm not used to normal/generic terms so may misuse them slightly.

I am building a database design which defines 'tasks' (a template of actions) and 'jobs' which are instantiations of tasks.

A task is defined in the TASKS table and will have a primary key TASK_ID. There is another table TASK_PARMS to define the attributes of the required parameters for a task. It has a composite primary key of TASK_ID and PARM_SEQ which defines the sequence of the parameters. There will be a foreign key on TASK_ID between TASK_PARMS and TASKS. These are then a template of how one performs a task (there are more attribute fields to actually define some actions, but they are not pertinent to this problem). Example table values below.

```
 TASKS                      TASK_PARMS
+---------+-----------+    +---------+----------+------------+
| TASK_ID | ATTRIBUTE |    | TASK_ID | PARM SEQ | ATTRIBUTES |
+---------+-----------+    +---------+----------+------------+
| FOO     | PGM_A     |    | FOO     |       10 | ALPHA10    |
+---------+-----------+    | FOO     |       20 | DEC5,0     |
                           +---------+----------+------------+
```

When I want to execute a task, I instantiate a job. The JOBS table has a primary key of JOB_ID and then needs to define which task template is being followed. So it has a foreign key to TASKS's primary key, TASK_ID.  As a job is comprised of (conceptually, is a copy of) a single task, this seems to be correct from a normalisation perspective.

There is a JOB_PARMS table which is used to hold the actual parameter values for this particular job. It has, of course, a JOB_ID foreign key to the JOBS table, but it must also have an exact relationship to the sequence numbers in TASK_PARMS.

```
 JOBS                      JOB_PARMS
+--------+-----------+    +---------+----------+-----------+
| JOB_ID | TASK_ID   |    | JOB_ID | PARM SEQ | VALUE      |
+---------+----------+    +--------+----------+------------+
|     99 | FOO       |    |     99 |       10 | XY1000AA   |
+--------+-----------+    |     99 |       20 | 2048       |
                          +--------+----------+------------+
```

Herein lies my problem. I cannot make the sequence field in JOB_PARMS a foreign key to TASK_PARMS because the TASK_ID is not present in JOB_PARMS.

This suggests that TASK_ID must be present in JOB_PARMS to allow the complete composite key for the foreign key relationship back to TASK_PARMS. However, as a job is really just an instantiation of a task, the TASK_ID field in JOB_PARMS will never change for a single value of JOB_ID. This seems to break normalisation.

I get the feeling I'm missing something here. I could just stick the TASK_ID in the JOB_PARMS file and get on with it but my sense of all that is right wants to know where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see anything wrong with having `TASK_ID` in `JOB_PARAMS` in your original.

However, if it looks too confusing you may try this one. The `TaskSequenceNo` increments for each task (1,2,3..) when a new job is created. The `Job_ID` is optional -- if present then `unique not null`.

[image]

There are two FK constraints on `JobParams`, something like (may need to adjust syntax):

```
alter table JobParams
  add constraint fk1_jp foreign key   (TaskId, TaskSequenceNo)
                        references Job(TaskId, TaskSequenceNo)

, add constraint fk2_jp foreign key   (TaskId, Param_Seq)
                 references TaskParams(TaskId, Param_Seq)
;
```

Comment: Thanks. Took me a while to get my head around it but I see now the basic approach is to instantiate the Task by extending its key (with `TaskSequenceNumber`) rather than replacing it - thus keeping the relationship with the Task intact.

Comment: The longer I look at this the more I see. Given the intention to keep `Job_ID` unique, it could actually be the second part of the key in `Job`. Then it's exactly what I had before but including `Task_ID` in the key. I think that's where my sense of normalisation was falling over. :-)